# how to create a shortcut link on Users machine for D:/ drive on a remote Server

Tags: windows, batch-file, sharing, administration

I have few remote servers for which i need to create shortcuts and put those shortcuts in a folder.And place it in users machine, so that when user clicks on the shortcut,User will get the explorer of D:\ drive on the remote server. Please help in this regard

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Thanks for making me do it. It was quite a simple task.

Comment: steps:1.share the drive to which we want to create shortcut. 2. Then go to another machine in the same network and click on control panel->network and internet connections->my network places. 3.click on add a network place. 4. enter//<server-ip>/<shared loc name>.In my case it was //10.10.20.12/d$. 5. Enter a name and click finish. After this we can create a shortcut on to desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example vbscript that'll do the trick I think.  ([credit where credit is due](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/msg/e8cc3cc8e6ee0fa9?dmode=source&hl=en&pli=1))

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sAllUsersDesktopPath = oShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop")

sWinSysDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%\System32")

Set oShortCut = oShell.CreateShortcut( _
         sAllUsersDesktopPath & "\D Drive on gibson.lnk")

oShortCut.TargetPath = sWinSysDir & "\Explorer.exe"
oShortCut.Arguments = "\\servername\d$"
oShortCut.IconLocation = sWinSysDir & "\Shell32.dll,10"
oShortCut.Save
```

Change the oShortCut.Arguments value as needed to point to the appropriate share on your servers, and change the "D drive on gibson" name as necessary.  Save this to a .vbs file and execute it with cscript or wscript.

Or you can try using the freeware [shortcut.exe from Optimum X](http://optimumx.com/downloads.html).

Comment: Thanks for the script. I have not tried it as windows helped me do it.